# plotly scattermapbox - issue with markers/plotting coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have some code that creates a list of dictionaries with coordinates to plot on the map and layout object. The map is rendering fine, however, there aren't any markers or coordinates. The data object contains a list of coordinates, so my suspicion is some issue with plotly/scattermapbox.

Here's my code:

```
def update_graph(selected_value):

    # Filter the dataframe with selected value
    Comp_data = EmpComm1[EmpComm1['Company'] == selected_value]

    data = []    
    # Plot home location and map commute to work. 
    # Create a data dictionary of lat and lon to plot
    for i, row in Comp_data.iterrows():

        lat, long = row['HomeLocation']

        data.append({
                    "type": "scattermapbox",
                    "lat": lat,
                    "lon": long,
                    "mode": "markers",
                    "marker": {
                        "symbol": "circle-dot",
                        "color": "grey",
                        "size": 10,
                        "opacity": 0.7
                        }
                    })


    layout = {
             "autosize": True,
             "hovermode": "closest",
             "mapbox": {
                 "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
                 "bearing": 0,
                 "center": {
                     "lat": 37.77,
                     "lon": -122.43
                 },
                 "pitch": 0,
                 "zoom": 10,
                 "style": "outdoors"
             }
    }    

    return {"data": data, "layout": layout}
```

Data Object:

```
[{'type': 'scattermapbox',
'lat': 37.70542367598618,
'lon': -121.83596766086245,
'mode': 'markers',
'marker': {'size': 3, 'opacity': 1.0}},
{'type': 'scattermapbox',
 'lat': 37.5646475449362,
 'lon': -121.78437649150582,
 'mode': 'markers',
 'marker': {'size': 3, 'opacity': 1.0}},
 .
 .
 .
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix:

```
"lat": [lat],

"lon": [long]
```

Needs to be a `list`, `numpy array` or `tuple`.